# Distinct Equivalence Classes of Congruence Modulo 4

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Let $A$ = $\{-4, -3, -2, -1, \space 0, \space1, \space2, \space3, \space4\}.$ $R$ is defined on $A$ as follows: For all $(m, n) \space\epsilon\space A,$

> $\space \space mRn \Leftrightarrow 4 \space\mid \space(m^{2} - n^{2})$

Find the distinct equivalence classes of $R$.

**What I did:**

- $m^{2} - n^{2} \Leftrightarrow m^{2} = n^{2} \space mod \space 4 \Leftrightarrow m = n \space mod \space 2 \Leftrightarrow m - n = 2k, \space k \space\epsilon\space \mathbb{Z}$

$[\space0\space]$ = $\{x \space \epsilon\space A \space\mid -x=2k\}$ (The numbers in this equivalence class differ from zero by a multiple of 2)

Therefore, $[\space 0\space]$ = $\{-4 ,-2 , \space0, \space2, \space4\}$

$[\space 1\space]$ =$\{x \space\epsilon\space A, \space\mid \space1-x=2k \}$

Therefore, $[\space 1\space]$ = $\{-3, -1, \space1, \space3 \}$

---

**Questions:**

I wanted to know if my working is right and if there is another way of solving this question.

In addition, is there a way of knowing from the get-go how many equivalence classes a relation to a particular set have?

Comment: The solution and method seem right! To your second question, I doubt it (unless it's a familiar equivalence relation); I think one just has to use one's cunning in each situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your working is right. There is just a typo : $$"\color{red}{4|}m^{2} - n^{2} \Leftrightarrow ..."$$

But I think this type of example deserves to be illustrated.

So we have a partition of $A$ $$A=A_0\cup A_1$$ with $\color{blue}{[0]=A_0=\{-4,-2,0,2,4\}}$ and $\color{red}{[1]=A_1=\{-3,-1,1,3\}}$

$\mathcal A\subset A\times A$ is represented on the top corner left.

As to whether there is a way to know from the start how many equivalence classes, I don't know of a general one.
[image]